# Formstack api give me back the same json all the time

Tags: php, api, formstack

*Edited 05-02-2013. I have updated the curl code.*

I have build a small class to work with formstack api. And I think that it works.

The problem is when I try to try all the leads from a form (more than 4000).

I build the urls with its page, time, and per_page param.

The strange is that Formstack give me back all the time the same json.

I have try that urls in a browser and it works great.

```
https://www.formstack.com/api/v2/form/xxxxxxxx/submission.json?oauth_token=xxxxthisismyoauthtokenxxxxx&per_page=100&min_time=2004-11-18 18:57:45&max_time=2013-02-04 18:57:45&page=0

https://www.formstack.com/api/v2/form/xxxxxxxx/submission.json?oauth_token=xxxxthisismyoauthtokenxxxxx&per_page=100&min_time=2004-11-18 18:57:45&max_time=2013-02-04 18:57:45&page=1
```

This is my curl code:

```
public function makeCurlGetCall($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/json')); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

  $result =  curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return $result;
}
```

As I have say, If I run the Curl method in a for loop to build all the page url I get the same json, but If I chech the url in a browser it works great.

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Clear your cache and restart your browser. It will work , the browser is caching the response and you are getting the same response each time. Or the other thing may be you can have errors in the loop itself.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=  $lead_decode->pages; $i++)
```

Comment: Hello, with the browser works great, the problem is with the Curls call.
Is there a cache in curl calls?

Comment: Hello Bhushan, sorry by the delay.
I have try "CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT", and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @OskarCalvo Just check your loop once or show the code..because everything here is fine now. Error must be in your loop somewhere...

Comment: Here is the function: http://pastebin.com/7KsrsUWN
And here is the class http://pastebin.com/Gn9Y3UUH I don't upload it to github because it's an alpha version, but it works. I want to check the name of all the elements before public a beta version of it.

Comment: I have make a change to the code, and seems to work know, The problem I have found is that the page 0 and the page 1 give back the same result. So the loop can't began with page 0, it must began with page 1.